# Delphi XE7 - Field FTBcd - Number is out of Range

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, tbcd

I am migrating an application from Delphi 2010 to Delphi XE7 that it uses some old Paradox Table with BDE. I have some fields formed BCD (#) Size 4 that in Delphi 2010 were managed as.asfloat

example

```
TABELLA1.Fieldbyname('FIELDBCD').AsFloat: = TABELLA2.Fieldbyname('Number').AsFloat;
```

without any problem.

In the converted program any type of assignment goes to error signalling EDBEngineError Number is out of range.... this even if I simply digit the value from a DBGrid.

Do you know of BUG in the management of the fields BCD in Delphi XE7 or must they have managed in different way?

Thanks
Mirko

Comment: Use `TField.AsBCD` instead.

Comment: I said that "this even if I simply digit the value from a DBGrid". The problem is independent from the type of assignment. Any type of assignment goes to error. I have 2 PC with delphi xe7 and in both the same problem. I have used any type of assignment (also .asbcd) but without results .

Comment: You're right. It's because of the type of the underlying value, which is why you should use `TField.AsBCD` instead as I said. Please post  a MCVE that contains sufficient information for us to reproduce the problem, including the Paradox table definitions and actual, compilable code.

Comment: Take a DBGrid, take a TTable and a TDatasource. Connect them. Connect a TTable to a Paradox Table with BDE Alias. It's sufficient the Paradox Table has a BCD Field. Modify the BCD Field of the Table by DBGrid and on the Post the error is "EDBEngineError Number is out of range"

Answer (score 0):

The ask is old, but I was still facing this problemn these days. I suggest confirm three properties.

precision - (It need to be the significative part and the fractionary part). For example, in data base the field is numeric(8,4), so here the correct value is 12

size - (Just the faccionary part of the number). In our example, the correct value is 4

DisplayWidth - Here we uses the value of the precision + 1, for the comma.